# Magento custom options grid

Tags: magento, grid

I have an extension for - Advanced custom options.
I would like to display the related options for every products in the order/grid.

This is the code I use:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');

$collection->getSelect()->join
(
'sales_flat_order_item',
'sales_flat_order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id',
array
(
'price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.price SEPARATOR "<br><br><hr>")'),
'proname' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.name SEPARATOR "<br><hr>")'),
'proptions' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.product_options SEPARATOR "<br><hr>")'),
)
   );

    $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

The result I get is incomplete array of the product option related to the product.

How can I get the (proptions) lables/title?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following line above your `return` statement and give me the output? I have a feeling if you're getting a partial response, it may be related to the SQL query itself.

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
```

You might also try giving leftJoin a shot instead of an inner join by using `$collection->getSelect()->leftJoin()`, depending on the structure of your query.